# Programmatically clicking toolbar button in parent of modal window

Tags: c++, winapi

I have an application that hooks into another application via an API. My application launches a modal window which prevents keypresses to reach the parent as one would expect.

However due to limitations in the API I need to click one of the parents toolbar buttons from time to time (yes it's a kludge).

I wonder if this is possible while still having the modal window of my application active? Is it perhaps possible to send the required command directly into the parent command queue?

Clicking the button programmatically with no modal window should not be a problem, one could go by this link for example: http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?307633-How-to-run-a-very-long-SQL-statement. But I would prefer not having to close my window each time I have to click the button.

Although the fifth answer is what I find interesting as I'm thinking this could make it possible to send the command without having to close my modal window first. Also it feels an ever so small bit less ugly.

Comment: Indeed I would try sending a WM_CLICK or similar message... I don't remember whether modality would prevent it from being processed. But are your toolbar buttons individual controls or is it a single control (hence possible issues for determining the proper position for the click, depending on resolution, font size, etc...) ?

Comment: One would probably have to locate them by ID each time as there is no way to guarantee that they are not moved around within the toolbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, when a modal dialog is shown, it runs its own message pump. So any attempt to fake input messages will land in the modal dialog message pump. Which is no good to you. So, you'd have to send a message rather than fake input.

However, when a modal dialog is shown, its owning windows are disabled. Which means that these windows will not respond to any messages you send. So I guess that means that you could:

1. Enable the owning top-level window that you hosts the toolbar in question.
2. Send the message to the toolbar button.
3. Disable the owning window again.

Not the prettiest way to go about things, but you did ask!